# SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503 in SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE app

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE RESTful Web Service app., using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_menu_alert_notification")
public class MenuAlertNotification implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public MenuAlertNotification() {
        super();
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;    

    @JsonProperty("subject")
    protected String subject;

    @JsonIgnore
    protected Integer trend;

    @JsonIgnore
    protected String message;

    @JsonProperty("notified")
    private Boolean notified;

    @Column(name = "is_read")
    protected Boolean read;

    @JsonProperty("creationDate")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.class)
    protected LocalDateTime creationDate;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "menu_alert_id")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="name")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    protected MenuAlert menuAlert;
..
}
```

and this method in the repository:

```
  @Transactional(propagation =Propagation.REQUIRED,
                    isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE,
                    readOnly=false,
                    transactionManager="transactionManager")
    @Modifying
        @Query("update MenuAlertNotification n set n.read = :status where n.id in :notificationIdList and n.menuAlert.menu.user.id = :userId")
        void changemenuNotificationListReadStatus(  @Param("notificationIdList") List<Long> notificationIdList, 
                                                        @Param("userId") long userId, 
                                                        @Param("status") boolean status);
```

I have created a Junit test :

```
MenuAlertNotification menuAlertNotification = new MenuAlertNotification (menuAlert);        
        menuAlertNotificationService.save(menuAlertNotification);               
        assertFalse (menuAlertNotification.getRead());      
        Long menuAlertNotificationId = menuAlertNotification.getId();       
        List<Long> notificationIdList = new ArrayList <Long>();     
        notificationIdList.add  (menuAlertNotificationId);

        menuAlertNotificationService
                .changeMenuNotificationReadStatus (notificationIdList, user.getId(), Boolean.TRUE);
```

when I save the object, everything is fine, but when I call the method `changeMenuNotificationReadStatus` I got this error:

```
019-04-16 11:21  [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(137) - SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
2019-04-16 11:21  [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(142) - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK56KKTN0YV9SJJIOJJVJBPAGNW: PUBLIC.T_MENU_ALERT_NOTIFICATION FOREIGN KEY(MENU_ALERT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.T_MENU_ALERT(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from t_menu_alert where id=? [23503-197]
```

Comment: i think problem lies in "n.menuAlert.menu.user.id = :userId" because you are access property of a child's child. and comparing it with id , thats why this issue is occurring. As MenuAlert is eager so it is fetched but its child not be fetched like menu and menu's child user , their FetchType will be Lazy. As they arenot fetch on runtime this issue could occur.

Comment: I'm guessing you are creating a new menuAlert in your unit test and the test framework is trying to delete it at the end of your test. Can you include the entire unit test with annotations on the test.

Comment: Yes please add the entire test if our answers didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please look at my answer and mark it accordingly if it is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using an In-memory database, and when the Test method is finished, Junit deletes all the tables but not in the correct order.

The Service layer code should be dependent on the Repository. However, to test the Service layer, you do not need to know or care about how the persistence layer is implemented.

Ideally, you should be able to write and test our Service layer code without wiring in our full persistence layer.

To achieve this, you can use the mocking support provided by Spring Boot Test.

Answer (score 3):

The ID is not generated when you do `MenuAlertNotification menuAlertNotification = new MenuAlertNotification (menuAlert);` as well as `Long menuAlertNotificationId = menuAlertNotification.getId();` this will always return `null`.

You should change the second line of your junit test to

```
menuAlertNotification = menuAlertNotificationService.save(menuAlertNotification);
```

I assume your service `menuAlertNotificationService.save(menuAlertNotification);` returns something like `return notificationRepo.save(entity)`.

This way you have the new object populated with ID after the row is inserted and hence will not get the stated exception.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by database going to delete a record is referred by other records with foreign key.(Foreign key constraint)

I guess in ur test case, before the code snippet that u have parsed here, there is a delete operation code, something like

```java
MenuAlertRepository.deleteAll()
```

Spring JPA will not execute this statement immediately when there is a transaction. After that Spring JPA met the JPQL query(changeMenuNotificationReadStatus), then it flushed all cached statements into db. At this time delete statement was being executed exactly. Then then Foreign key constraint exception was thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

As Jian said, it's not the call to changeMenuNotificationReadStatus that causes the error, but probably a previous statement which was not flushed.

Something is generating this delete statement, which is responsible of FK constraint violation:

```
delete from t_menu_alert where id=?
```

In your tests, you could use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`, and `flush` methods regularly to issue SQL modification requests and see where to problem is.

Here, JPA is trying to delete `MenuAlert` before deleting the referencing  `MenuAlertNotification`, so the FK constraint blocks as you probably know.

As a notification makes no sense for a deleted alert, you could also cascade the deletion:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

or change the FK constraint `ON DELETE` action at database level: CASCADE will delete the referenceing `MenuAlertNotification`s and SET NULL will clear the association by setting null on referencing `MenuAlertNotification.menuAlert`.

You can also write java code to delete the `MenuAlertNotification`s before the `MenuAlert`, based on conditions.

I'd be curious to read your whole testing code.

Adil Khalil, you're right that if Spring Data JPA Repository.save method is used directly, we need to get the return value to have the updated id. But here, I think he calls a service layer that shall return the updated value:

```
@Service
public class MenuAlertNotificationService {
    private MenuAlertNotificationRepository repository;

    public MenuAlertNotification save(MenuAlertNotification entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    } 
}
```